# batch processing markdown into a template

Tags: print-production, template-design

I have an existing PSD template for a print design, though I can change that to anything else for the purposes of this project.

I want to use GPT to batch create a set of markdown files that I am going to print out using the template. These include mostly plain text, but one section that is a `code block` section where I want to have color-coded Python against a black background.

What is the best way to "mail merge" my markdown files with the template to create a finished project to print?

Comment: If it's "mostly plain text" why are you using Photoshop?

Comment: the overall template / design for the print is in photoshop. it will be filled in with dynamic content.

Comment: Probably easier to do with Indesign, as you have data merge feature.